# How can I make my own pool?

Tags: mining-pools, p2pool, pushpool

Me and my friends want to make public pool like rublik.com (site have english vesrion).
So, how can we make a similar pool? Maybe there are some open source solutions like p2pool? We want to make a similar pool, maybe someone knows what solutions rublik.com use? We just want to copy their pool.

Comment: "possible duplicate" maybe clarify on both if its about a public or private pool, thats two different pairs of shoes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running a public pool comes with the obligation to understand the underlying asset.

Rublik seems to have own proprietary software.

To run a public pool you at least need the following:

1. Knowledge of linux system administration/security.
2. A dedicated server.
3. A coder to write/edit a frontend, reward structure and payout process.
4. Of course the pool software.

Expect if you run a puplic pool to deal with system exploitation and Ddos.

There is opensource pool software available. However, most are outdated, open exploits or other issues. Either code your own, improve existing software or do DD on maintained software (eloipool by luke-jr --> IRC freenode `#eligius` for example is maintained).

Just a hint:
https://www.google.com/search?q=bitcoin+pool+software&ie=UTF-8&sa=Search&channel=fe&client=browser-ubuntu&hl=en

There are opensource frontends too but those available last i checked are no out of the box solutions.

Even if you get that far you will face the task to create a reward structure with automatic payout process.

To underline that again: 90% of available opensource software needs workovers, some aren’t maintained for over a year, you hardly will find outofthebox solutions for free.

Comment: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=89873.msg989308#msg989308   maybe useful, comments by Ozco.in owner.

Comment: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Poolservers  **Poolservers**